# What is the method for pooling when Paule-Mandel estimator is used in package metafor?

Tags: r

Consider the code below which determines a random effect model with a Paule-Mandel estimator for heterogeneity:

```
library(metafor)
res = rma(measure = "RD", ai = Ai, bi =  Bi, ci = Ci, di = Di, data = data1, method="PM")
```

In package metafor manual the method for pooling is mentioned in the case  Hunter-Schmidt or DerSimonian-Laird estimators are used for pooling results, but not mentioned for Paule-Mandel estimator. Any hints?

Comment: Could you show the example from the manual of what you're looking for in the case of the other estimators?

Comment: In details for `rma.uni`, below methods of heterogeneity, it says: _Finally, the generalized Q-statistic estimator is a general method-of-moments estimator requiring the specification of weights (the HE and DL estimators are just special cases with equal and inverse variance weights, respectively)._

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is the use of the term 'pooling' here. I don't see anything from that quote that jumps out at me as being pooling and I don't see that term used anywhere in the manual. Also, `HE` is actually the Hedges estimator (`HS` is Hunter-Schmidt and  `GENQ` is the Q-statistic). But in the sentence before the one you quoted it gives the reference for the `PM` estimator that was implemented, so shouldn't the answer be in that paper (Paule & Mandel, 1982)?

Comment: You might also just want to look at the source. I read the source of the `"PM"` method for the `rma` function but nothing jumped out at me as what I'd call pooling by any statistical definition I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for following the discussion. That's right, the word pooling is not used there. That means the estimator used for combining the estimates of different studies. It's usually the weighted average of estimates, but the method for calculating the weights differs. It's usually the inverse of variance of each study as said for DL method above. So I looked up in the reference of PM method as suggested by you, and found that it uses sort of an iterative method for finding weights. I think that does not have a specific name as I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paule-Mandel (PM) estimator is a method for estimating the amount of heterogeneity (usually denoted tau^2 in the meta-analytic literature). Once this variance component has been estimated, nothing different happens than with any of the other methods: We just compute the weighted average of the estimates, using 1/(sampling variance + tau^2) as the weights. To illustrate:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data = dat, method="PM")
res
coef(res)
weighted.mean(dat$yi, 1/(dat$vi + res$tau2))
```

The last two lines give you the same value: `-0.7149682`.

**Edit:** The Mantel-Haenszel method also computes a weighted average. In the example above, `escalc()` computes the log risk ratios (and corresponding sampling variances) and we then compute the weighted mean based on the log risk ratios. The MH method works a bit different in that it computes a weighted average based on the risk ratio values directly. To illustrate:

```
res <- rma.mh(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res
exp(coef(res))
weighted.mean(exp(dat$yi), weights(res))
```

The last two lines both give the same value: `0.6352672`.

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang. So this means all random effect models use different estimators for heterogeneity, but at the end, the weighted average with the weights mentioned above is used? What about Mantel-Haenszel Method which is for fixed effects? I think it does not use the weighted average method for comibining the estimates.

Comment: As for your first question, yes (assuming you are sticking to the standard methods; there are other approaches of course). As for your second question, also MH computes a weighted average. See my edit.